# How to symbolically do matrix "Block Inversion"?

Tags: matrix, symbolic, inverse, linear-algebra

Consider a block (partitioned) matrix

```
matrix = ArrayFlatten[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]
```

where, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are each matrices themselves. Say, for example,

```
a = {{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}}
b = {{b11, b12}, {b21, b22}}
c = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
d = {{d11, d12}, {d21, d22}}
```

How can you find the *block* inverse of this matrix? A desired solution is, using the example above

```
{{Inverse[a] , -Inverse[a].b.Inverse[d]},{0,Inverse[d]}}
```

which is easily verified using

```
Simplify[Inverse[ArrayFlatten[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]] == 
ArrayFlatten[{{Inverse[a], -Inverse[a].b.Inverse[d]}, {0, 
 Inverse[d]}}]]
```

which yields `True`.

How can you solve the block inverse problem
for arbitrary submatrices, and for block matrices of larger sizes (i.e. 3x3, 4x4, etc)?

Comment: The simplest way may be to define a function which does exactly that. OF course in the general case this is complicated, but if you're doing only 2x2 or 2^n x 2^n matrices it shouldn't be terribly hard.

Comment: @MikeBantegui Any specific suggestions? A function is fine.

Comment: I'll add an answer that demonstrates this.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Mathematica does not support this directly. You can do things of this sort using an external package called NCAlgebra.

http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/

The relevant documentation may be found at

http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/DOWNLOAD2010/DOCUMENTATION/html/NCBIGDOCch4.html#x8-510004.4

In particular have a look at "4.4.8 NCLDUDecomposition[aMatrix, Options]"

Using this package, you would find the block inverse of the example `matrix` using:

```
c=0;    
inverse = NCInverse[matrix]  
(* Out[] = {{inv[a], -inv[a] ** b ** inv[d]}, {0, inv[d]}} *)
```

Here `inv[a]` represents the general inverse of the `a` block of the matrix and the `**` represents non-commutative (i.e. matrix) multiplication. This approach works for larger (3x3, 4x4, etc) square block matrices as well.

Comment: Any updates on this after 7 years? Is there a new approach?

Answer (score 15):

For a general square matrix `m` and arbitrary partition of it into conformable parts `m={{a,b},{c,d}}` (i.e., `a` and `d` are square matrices, and `b` and `c` have appropriate dimensions),

[image: partitioned matrix]

the formula for the inverse (which can be found in, for example, [Review of Matrix Algebra](http://halweb.uc3m.es/esp/Personal/personas/durban/esp/web/notes/matrixintr.pdf)) is

```
 m={{a,b},{c,d}};
 e = d - c.Inverse[a].b; 
 minv={{Inverse[a] + Inverse[a].b.Inverse[e].c.Inverse[a],
          -Inverse[a].b.Inverse[e]}, 
       {-Inverse[e].c.Inverse[a], Inverse[e]}};
```

[image]

This can be used to define a function that takes a matrix and a partition specification and does the needed type and conformability checks before applying the formula. You can use @Mike's formulation (and, off course, heed his warnings) as a first step:

```
Clear[sInverse2];
sInverse2[{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}] := 
With[{e = d - c.Inverse[a].b}, 
     {{Inverse[a] + Inverse[a].b.Inverse[e].c.Inverse[a], 
         -Inverse[a].b.Inverse[e]}, 
      {-Inverse[e].c.Inverse[a], Inverse[e]}}]
```

Answer (score 11):

In general this is not an easy thing to do, and a package as Daniel Lichtblau suggested may be your best bet.

However in the specialized case of a 2^n x 2^n matrix, the inversion is very well known.

The case mentioned in your post is:

```
Clear[sInverse]; (* s for symbolic *)
sInverse[{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}] := 
      {{Inverse[a], -Inverse[a] . b . Inverse[d]}, {0, Inverse[d]}}
```

However you can recursively define this function in terms of itself:

```
sInverse[{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}] := 
 {{sInverse[a], -sInverse[a].b.sInverse[d]}, {0, sInverse[d]}}
```

This however will crap out on you completely if you actually try this. We have to add some stopping condition to this:

```
sInverse[{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}] /;
  (! ListQ[a]) && (! ListQ[b]) && (! ListQ[c]) && (! ListQ[d]) := 
 a d - b c {{d, -b}, {-c, a}}
```

This itself also has some issues. Notably, when it reaches the base case you're going to get expressions like -(-a b + c d) . {{m1, m2}, {m3, m4}} . (-p q + r s).

**As it stands, this will not get you the exact expression you need.** To get things to come out nicely you're going to have to include some more logic in there to flatten the lists out and account for multiplication of matrices and non-matrices. I'm not quite sure how it can be done at this moment, but when I think of it I'll add it.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but I thought block wise inversion was very well known for [4-blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_inverse#Blockwise_inversion), provided that the blocks on the diagonal were square.