# Can Mathematica do symbolic linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, symbolic

For instance, is there some way I can say "let A and B be arbitrary real $m\times n$ and $k\times m$ matrices, `Simplify[Transpose[Transpose[A].Transpose[B]]]`" and Mathematica would simplify it to `B.A`?

I know I can set A and B to be matrices containing symbols (e.g. `A = Table[Subscript[a,i,j],{i,m},{j,n}]`), but results can get quite messy if the problem is more complex than `Transpose[Transpose[A].Transpose[B]]`

**EDIT**: To answer @Searke and @Artes questions in the comments: I'm currently watching this [Stanford online machine learning course](http://www.ml-class.org). If you look at the [lecture notes](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes1.pdf), pages 8-11, you see a some matrix calculations. I can follow these calculations with pen and paper, but I haven't found a way to derive e.g. this result from page 11 using Mathematica:

[image]

Comment: Nope.

The issue is that for a given symbol there is no way to say "Oh this symbol is a symmetric, real matrix."

To the best of my knowledge, there is no package for this.

Comment: I would actually be very interested in hearing what people think such functionality should be able to do. Does some other software do this and how do they do it?

Comment: See related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-to-symbolically-do-matrix-block-inversion

Comment: What about this answer? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16378/1089

Comment: There's a MatrixD package that lets you differentiate matrix expressions -- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138708/differentiating-functions-of-vectors-matrices/141237#141237

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the posted example, [`TensorReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce.html) does the trick:

```
TensorReduce[
  Transpose[Transpose[A].Transpose[B]], 
  Assumptions -> {A ∈ Matrices[{m, n}], B ∈ Matrices[{k, m}]}
]
```

> ```
> B.A
> ```

Answer (score 28):

Initially, Mathematica is not designed for such abstract calculations.

But, Mathematica is a powerful programming language, so that one can add such functionality easily.

See the following examples in related area of differential geometry:

- calculations in [symbolic dimensions](https://web.archive.org/web/20170930003852/http://digi-area.com/Mathematica/atlas/tutorial/Dimension.php)
- [Abstract calculations](https://web.archive.org/web/20170807111901/http://digi-area.com/Mathematica/atlas/tutorial/Abstract.php)

Comment: Links are dead.

Comment: @jlh, that vendor seems to be no more, but I've added links to the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 19):

Indeed this is a one liner in [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC):

```
<< NC`
<< NCAlgebra`
NCGrad[1/2 (x ** z - y)^T ** (x ** z - y), z]
```

which results in

> -y^T ** x + z^T ** x^T ** x

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure, but maybe this software for Mathematica http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/ could somehow help. The software is for a package called NCAlgebra developed by UC San Diego. I am not familiar with the detailed usage, but it claims to implement capability to study noncommutative inequalities, linear controls, and semidefinite programming within Mathmeatica.

Comment: Hi Konstantin, welcome to Mathematica.SE. Can you add some information about the software here? When that link dies ("when", not "if") your answer becomes useless.