# Non-commutative symbolic linear algebra

Tags: matrix, symbolic

I am fairly new to Mathematica but I thought I would be a helpful tool to carry out a few simple linear algebra calculations. It seems like an easy task but I cannot figure out how to do it. For example, say I want to multiply two matrices composed of sub-matrices:

```
P := {{P1, P12}, {P12\[Transpose], P2}}; Q := {{Q1, Q12}, {Q12\[Transpose], Q2}};
P.Q
```

but it returns:

```
{{P1 Q1 + P12 Transpose[Q12], P1 Q12 + P12 Q2}, 
 {Q1 Transpose[P12] + P2 Transpose[Q12], P2 Q2 + Q12 Transpose[P12]}}
```

How can I get a non-commutative result (e.g. the bottom left element should be `P12\[Transpose] Q1`)? Also, how do I get it to show the little transpose 'T' instead of writing it out?

I found similar questions posted:

[Can Mathematica do symbolic linear algebra?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3242/can-mathematica-do-symbolic-linear-algebra)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708208/symbolic-matrices-in-mathematica-with-unknown-dimensions

but I'm not trying to do anything as complicated as those.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html

Comment: Transpose 'T':  Just type esc-tr-esc after the matrix and it's done.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Searke hints at the answer. Remembering that the dot product is a specific form of `Inner`:

```
Inner[Times,P,Q,Plus]
```

We can simply replace `Times` wtih `NonCommutativeMultiply`

```
Inner[NonCommutativeMultiply, P, Q, Plus]
```

With the output:

```
{
 {P1 ** Q1 + P12 ** Transpose[Q12],P1 ** Q12 + P12 ** Q2}, 
 {P2 ** Transpose[Q12] + Transpose[P12] ** Q1, P2 ** Q2 + Transpose[P12] ** Q12}
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to get into this topic there is an `NonCommutativeMultiply (**)`

and a tutorial on [**Flat and Orderless Functions**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FlatAndOrderlessFunctions.html).

Comment: Good point: `Attributes[Times]` gives  `{Flat, Listable, NumericFunction, OneIdentity, Orderless, Protected}`