# Non Commutative Multiply

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non-commutative symbolic linear algebra](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/non-commutative-symbolic-linear-algebra)

I want to multiply two matrices, for example,

```
A = {{e, f}, {g, h}}
B = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
```

Using `A.B`, *Mathematica* returns

```
{{a e + b g, a f + b h}, {c e + d g, c f + d h}}
```

I would like to get, however, the following result:

```
{{e a + f c, e b + f d}, {g a + h c, g b + h d}}
```

since, for me, the entries `{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}` are operators, i.e. they are non-commutative.

I could solve this problem clearing the attribute `Orderless` in the built-in function `Times`:

```
ClearAttributes[Times, Orderless]
```

I know, however, this can be dangerous. I tried to define a function

```
Times2[a_,b_]:=Times[a,b]
```

and then use `ClearAttributes[Times2, Orderless]` but it doesn't work.

How could I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look up `Inner[]` and `NonCommutativeMultiply[]`.

Comment: more precisely `Inner[NonCommutativeMultiply, A, B]`

Comment: The reason `Times2[a_,b_]:=Times[a,b]` doesn't work when as you expect when `Times2` is not orderless, is that it only affects the left hand side. You are just passing onwards to `Times` which is still orderless.

Comment: This answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5458/1194 by Leonid Shifrin shows how it's possible to circumvent the orderless property of `Times` when applied to specific expressions, without having to remove it.

Comment: If you like to live dangerously you can always do `Unprotect[Times];ClearAttributes[Times, Orderless];Protect[Times]; A.B` Though it is typically ill advised to mess with the behaviour of low level functions like Times

Comment: Thanks for comments! I already tried using NonCommutativeMultiply and Inner, but sometimes I will need to multiply three matrices, one of it possible having scalar entries. Then, I believe the best thing to me is try to define a Times2 function. I was not able to this yet, but I'm trying. thanks!