# Symbolic linear algebra gradients/matrix calculus

Tags: linear-algebra, symbolic, calculus-and-analysis

Can Mathematica generate symbolic expressions for gradients?

For example, if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two points, could I get Mathematica to generate expressions similar to the following?

$\frac{\partial \left|x_1 - x_2\right|}{\partial x_1} = \frac{x_1 - x_2}{\left|x_1 - x_2\right|}$

$\frac{\partial \left|x_1 - x_2\right|}{\partial x_2} = \frac{x_2 - x_1}{\left|x_1 - x_2\right|}$

My experience with Mathematica is limited. I know how to get derivatives w.r.t. scalars.

Elsewhere on this site I found [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3242/can-mathematica-do-symbolic-linear-algebra) question and from the answers it looks like Mathematica recently acquired the ability to do some amount of symbolic linear algebra.

Comment: `D[Sqrt[(x1 - x2) (x1 - x2)], x1]`? If `x1` and `x2` are supposed to be vectors, then I think your expressions are wrong, because the left-hand-side is a scalar, and the right-hand side is a vector.

Comment: @march Both sides are a vector. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$ refers to the vector of derivatives with respect to each component of $x_1$.

Comment: So, you mean the gradient?

Comment: @march Mostly yes, but split it into portions due to $x_1$ and $x_2$. I'm not sure if there's a better way to refer to that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything you want in the question can be done by defining the derivative of the `Norm`:

```
Derivative[1][Norm][z_] := z/Norm[z]

D[Norm[x - y], {x}]
(* ==> (x - y)/Norm[x - y] *)

Simplify[D[Norm[x - y], {y}]]
(* ==> (-x + y)/Norm[x - y] *)
```

Here, the syntax I used for the derivatives is such that it would remain valid if `x` or `y` were replaced by vectors (i.e., `List`s).

Comment: Is there a way to load definitions for derivatives of common linear algebra expressions "out of the box"?

Comment: Not really. For most purposes, it's still necessary to either use explicit component notation (i.e., replace `x` by `{xa, xb, xc}` etc.) or to add your own definitions as I did here, or to use `$Assumptions` in combination with  `TensorReduce` because by default interpretation of symbols like `x` and `y` is simply that they are generic complex scalars. It's especially difficult to "simplify" vector calculus expressions automatically because it's not as easy to characterize what constitutes a "simpler" result.

Answer (score 2):

To some extent (and with some care) this can be done with FeynCalc. At least I used it several times when I needed to compute gradients and divergences of Cartesian vectors. The trick is to work with D-dimensional 4-vectors and take the limit $D \to 3$ at the end. Since FeynCalc doesn't distinguish between upper and lower indices, the results are the same as if one would work with Cartesian vectors. For example, computing $\partial x_1^i/ \partial x_1^j$ via

```
FourDivergence[FVD[x1, i], FVD[x1, j]]
```

returns $g^{i j}$ which one should interpret as a Kronecker delta. For the examples from the OP's question we can use

```
FourDivergence[Sqrt[SPD[x1 - x2]], FVD[x1, i]] // Together
```

to get

$\frac{\text{x1}^i-\text{x2}^i}{\sqrt{\text{x1}^2-2 (\text{x1} \cdot \text{x2} \cdot )+\text{x2}^2}}$

and

```
FourDivergence[Sqrt[SPD[x1 - x2]], FVD[x2, i]] // Together
```

to obtain

$\frac{\text{x2}^i-\text{x1}^i}{\sqrt{\text{x1}^2-2 (\text{x1} \cdot \text{x2} \cdot )+\text{x2}^2}}$

This is of course not a general solution, but I find it quite useful from time to time, so why not share it here. If one wants something more general, then the xTensor package might be worth a try.