# Is it possible to do matrix algebra symbolically?

Tags: matrix, algebraic-manipulation

I'm reading a book that has the following theorem:

> [image]

I am trying to make Mathematica perform these calculations for me. Is it possible to do it without having to declare the matrices? For example, I tried to write: `Transpose[A.B]`. I expected it to return $B^TA^T$ or something similar, but it actually doesn't do that. At least in a trivial way.

Comment: It may be possible to carry out symbolic matrix algebra once you provide appropriate assumptions: see e.g. [`Matrices`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Matrices.html?q=Matrices) and, more generally, [Symbolic Tensors](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SymbolicTensors.html).

Comment: Related: [Can Mathematica do symbolic linear algebra?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3242/27951), [Can I use symbolic tensors for simple linear algebra and calculus?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52213/27951), [(19934)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19934/27951), [(118855)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118855/symbolic-linear-algebra-gradients-matrix-calculus#comment321363_118858).

Comment: Take a look at NCAlgebra and if you can do the above calculations with it, please post a self-answer.