# Simplifying symbolic products of matrices

Tags: matrix, symbolic

(This is probably a trivial question, but I could not find the answer in the documentation.)

I would like to be able to use (functions similar to) `Simplify`, `Factor` etc. on products and sums of arbitrary *symbolic* matrices.

For example, I would like behavior similar to the following:

```
Simplify[a.b + a.c + a.d]
--> a.(b + c + d)

Simplify[Tr[a.b.c] + Tr[b.c.a] + Tr[c.a.b]]
--> 3 Tr[a.b.c]

Simplify[Tr[a.ConjugateTranspose[b] + b.ConjugateTranspose[a]]]
--> 2 Re[Tr[a.ConjugateTranspose[b]]]
```

I have tried adding Assumptions that `a`,`b`,`c` and `d` are matrices, as follows:

```
$Assumptions = {
    a\[Element] Matrices[{2, 2}, Complexes, {}],
    b\[Element] Matrices[{2, 2}, Complexes, {}],
    c\[Element] Matrices[{2, 2}, Complexes, {}],
    d\[Element] Matrices[{2, 2}, Complexes, {}]
}
```

but this does not work.
Is there an inbuilt way to get these types of simplifications to work in Mathematica, or do I need to write my own functions to do this?

Comment: It cannot be done with built-ins without writing your own methods. You will probably want to look at the non-commutative algebra package https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC and specifically the matrices section: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/DOCUMENTATION/#AdvancedMatrices

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful!

Comment: ^ well it's a bit clunky but better than nothing. However, there is also `TensorReduce`. See this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/221745/72682