# Reduce equations formed of symbolic matrices and vectors

Tags: symbolic

I was defining the following assumptions

```mathematica
$Assumptions = {A ∈ Matrices[{3, 3}, Reals], 
  x ∈ Vectors[3, Reals], b ∈ Vectors[3, Reals]}
```

```mathematica
Reduce[A . x == b, x]
```

or

```mathematica
Solve[A . x == b, x]
```

None of them is working. I was expecting something in the lines of x = Inv(A).b

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Hint: `MatrixQ[A]` returns `False`

Comment: `I was expecting something in the lines of x = Inv(A).b` presupposes that `A` is non-singular.

Comment: Can I define A as non singular and get then the desired result. I just want to reduce equations...

Comment: If you want others to see your comments you should tag them. For instance you should write something like @Syed

Comment: I don't know of a way to restrict 3x3 matrices to the non-singular ones only. Thanks @bmf for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed in the following way to obtain an analytic solution, albeit not as compact as one might have hoped for.

```
n = 3;
amat = Array[a, {n, n}];
xvec = Array[x, n];
bvec = Array[b, n];
sltn = Solve[amat . xvec - bvec == 0, xvec] // Flatten // 
   FullSimplify;
```

And now you can check your solution

```
xvec /. sltn // MatrixForm
```

> [image: mat]

You can, also, check explicitly with the expected compact answer

```
LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ[(Inverse[amat] . bvec // 
    FullSimplify) - (xvec /. sltn)]
```

> [image: true]

Comment: This seems overly complicated for such a simple linear equations ... where I just want a reduce of the equation

Comment: @AndreiChalapco I understand that it seems like that, but perhaps you want to have a look [`here`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3242/can-mathematica-do-symbolic-linear-algebra) and understand why I suggested the above solution :-)