# Make Times non-commutative only for a specific set of expressions

Tags: attributes

I'm making a small hacky notebook and want to avoid using external libraries. In my notebook, I'd like multiplication to be non-commutative only for a particular family of expressions whilst still using `Times` (not `NonCommutativeMultiply`).

The expressions have the form `Subscript[symb_Symbol, _Integer]` where `symb` is a member of (e.g.) [`A`, `B`, `C`]. There are few symbols, so I'm happy to hardcode rules.

I'd like, for example

```
Times[Subscript[B, 2], Subscript[A, 1]]
```

to be unchanged, rather than have the order of the terms automatically commuted.

I've seen [this solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5444/is-it-possible-to-get-the-order-of-inputs-when-overloading-an-orderless-functi/5458#5458) where `Times` of a particular Head `matrix` is made non-commutative, and I've seen how [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/blob/master/NCAlgebra/NonCommutativeMultiply.m) does it, but I can't manage to adapt either for my purposes.

I'd actually prefer to substitute `Times` for `Dot` when it contains one of these expressions. I know I can define a function with the `HoldAll` attribute and replace `Times` to `Dot` before Mathematica commutes the expression, but I'd like this behaviour everywhere, not just in the function argument.

In affect, this would give behaviour like (for special symbols `A`, `B`, `C`):

$B_2 A_2 + G F E$ would evaluate to $B_2 . A_2 + E F G$

Is this possible without immense complication?

Comment: I'm thinking this is either not possible and not recommended.

Comment: As a workaround try this: `ClearAttributes[Times, Orderless]; 
Times[x___, Subscript[a_, n_], y___] ^:= Dot[x, Subscript[a, n], y]`. It will use `Dot` instead of `Times` every time a `Subscript` appears inside `Times`. It's necessary to clear `Orderless` attribute in order to preserve the order of arguments though.

Comment: @QuantumDot All the interesting things are :)

Comment: Why do you insist on using `Times`?  Mathematica tends to be unpredictable sometimes.  Based on past experience, I would not dare mess with such a fundamental built-in as `Times`.

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfied your need? There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. One weeks is enough wait. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Comment: It hasn't even been 1 week. Thanks for the condescension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perhaps get what you want by using [`$Pre`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Pre.html):

```
$Pre = 
  Function[{arg}, 
   ReleaseHold[
    Hold[arg] //.  
     Times[α___, 
       patt : (Longest[
          Subscript[_Symbol, _Integer] ..]), ω___] :> 
      Times[α, Dot[patt], ω]], HoldAll];

x y + a c Subscript[B, 2] Subscript[A, 1] b

(* ==> x y + a b c Subscript[B, 2].Subscript[A, 1] *)

a b Subscript[A, 10] Subscript[B, 2] Subscript[A, 1] c

(* ==> a b c Subscript[A, 10].Subscript[B, 2].Subscript[A, 1] *)
```

The replacement rule also merges dot products that are interspersed with commutative multiplications:

```
a c Subscript[B, 2] Subscript[A, 1] b Subscript[B, 3] Subscript[A, 4]

(*
==> a b c Subscript[B, 2].Subscript[A, 1].Subscript[B, 3].Subscript[A, 4]
*)
```

Comment: This is brilliant :) Can I expect any adverse side effects?

Comment: This is the least invasive way I could think of. And in principle you could make the pattern more restrictive if there are other subscripted objects that need to be treated differently. So I'd say any side effects should be manageable if your notebook has a well-defined scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[times]
times[a___, Longest@PatternSequence[b_Subscript, c___, d_Subscript], e___] := 
   Times[a, e, ## & @@ Cases[{b, c, d}, Except[_Subscript], 1] , 
     Dot @@ Cases[{b, c, d}, _Subscript, 1]]
times[a___]:= Times[a]
```

**Examples:**

```
times[a, b, Subscript[B, 3], y, Subscript[C, 3], w, z, Subscript[A, 2], 2, t]
```

> 2 a b t w y z Subscript[B, 3].Subscript[C, 3].Subscript[A, 2]

```
Inactivate[Times[Subscript[B, 2], Subscript[A, 1], J] + F G H, Times] /. 
   Times -> times // Activate // TeXForm
```

> $J B_2.A_1+F G H$

For version 9 and earlier versions

```
Hold[Times[Subscript[B, 2], Subscript[A, 1], J] + F G H] /. Times -> times //
 ReleaseHold // TeXForm
```

> $J B_2.A_1+F G H$

Stealing from Jens's great idea, wee can also use `times` to specify `$Pre`:

```
$Pre = Function[{arg}, Activate[Inactivate[arg, Times] /. Times -> times], HoldAll];(*or*)
$Pre = Function[{arg}, ReleaseHold[Hold[arg] /. Times -> times],  HoldAll];
```