# Verifying and deriving basic (block) matrix identities

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic, tensors

How can I use the new symbolic matrix/tensor capabilities to verify matrix identities, such as

[image]  (1)

or

[image] (2)

Even better, how can I ask Mathematica to derive expressions for X, Y, Z, and U like the ones shown on the RHS of (2) (many equivalent forms exist) (and as a bonus, display them similarly).

Comment: did you try 'Solve'?

Comment: For the second part of the question (not specific to version 9), see [Matrix multiplication in Block Form symbolic calculation by Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7902/245)

Comment: A closely related question is also: [Can Mathematica do symbolic linear algebra?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3242/245). Your question is more specific, but the answers there provide some important information, I think.

Comment: Yes, thanks, and prior to posting this question I had seen the above posts.  They all predate V9.0 though. I was hoping for a few magic one-liners in V9.0 that would do the same...

Comment: OK - so it looks like we'll have to keep hoping for version 10 to get this as a built-in capability, which would be really cool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formulas involving inverses are special to matrices--neither vectors nor higher-rank tensors have a notion of inverse.  As a result, the current framework has only limited support for identities involving inverses.  It deals best with identities involving tensor products, symmetries, and contractions, which are fundamental to all tensor operations.  We hope to add better support for matrices inversion in a future release.

Comment: How about block matrices? Can I define A, B, C, and D to be symbolic n x n, n x m, m x n, and m x m matrices and then have mathematica recognize something like E = SymbolicArrayFlatten[{{A,B},{C,D}}] as an (n+m) x (n+m) matrix?

Comment: Block matrices are also not supported at this time.  As you point out, we will need to add new symbols to support these, because if A,B, C and D are matrices, {{A,B},{C,D}} is a rank-3 array.

Comment: I definately would appreciate that support. Big interest :)