# Partitioned matrix operations

Tags: matrix

I have a $(2 \times 2)$ matrix whose elements are themselves $(2 \times 2)$ matrices (i.e., a *partitioned matrix*), e.g:
$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix}, \quad \quad \text{with } A,B,C,D \in \text{Mat}_{2 \times 2}. $$
**Problem:** I want to compute some things with this matrix, in particular an expression for $M^{n}$, I have tried using `MatrixPower[M, n]` in *Mathematica* but this does not work, (the error message says that the argument at position 1 is not a non-empty square matrix). If I pretend that $A,B,C,D$ are scalars then *Mathematica* will automatically assume multiplicative commutativity when computing powers of $M$.

**Additional info**: Furthermore, matrix multiplication does not work, if I try $M.M$ then I expect to obtain a result which looks like:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} A.A + B.C & A.B+B.D \\ C.A+D.C &C.B+D.D \end{pmatrix}, $$
however, instead, I obtain a result in which the entries of $M.M$ are $(2 \times 2)$ matrices of $(2 \times 2)$ matrices (a bit complicated to explain).

Many thanks if someone can tell me how to compute matrix powers of a matrix whose elements are themselves matrices.

Comment: It looks to me that your expected result is incorrect. Could you check?

Comment: Apologies, it is now amended.

Comment: Similar problem/question is discussed here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7902/matrix-multiplication-in-block-form-symbolic-calculation-by-mathematica "Matrix multiplication in Block Form symbolic calculation by Mathematica".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use the symbolic representation of the block matrix and perform the matrix operations with `Inner` and `NonCommutativeMultiply`. At the end we replace the matrix blocks with numeric or symbolic matrices. Below is an example.

The package and articles at ["Noncommutative Algebra Package and Systems"](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/4594/) might be of interest if these kind of manipulations are going to be done often and in more general form.

Here is a block matrix in symbolic form:

```
blockMat = {{A11, A12}, {A21, A22}};
MatrixForm[blockMat]
```

Here is the matrix multiplication using `Inner` and `NonCommutativeMultiply`.

```
blockMat2 = 
  Outer[Inner[NonCommutativeMultiply, #1, #2, Plus] &, blockMat, 
   Transpose[blockMat], 1];
MatrixForm[blockMat2, 1]
```

Note that the use of `Inner` directly corresponds to the block-matrix row-by-column multiplication.

This replaces the symbols for the matrix blocks with numerical matrices:

```
nBlockMat2 = 
  blockMat2 /. {A11 -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}], 
    A12 -> RandomReal[{10, 11}, {2, 2}], 
    A21 -> RandomReal[{100, 101}, {2, 2}], 
    A22 -> RandomReal[{1000, 1001}, {2, 2}]};
```

This command makes the sub-matrix multiplications:

```
MatrixForm[nBlockMat2 /. NonCommutativeMultiply -> Dot]
```

The above result with `ArrayFlatten` applied to it:

```
MatrixForm[ArrayFlatten[nBlockMat2 /. NonCommutativeMultiply -> Dot]]
```

Here is an image of the above in a Mathematica session:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have realised it is a simple answer, I can just regard $M$ as a $(4 \times 4)$ matrix, eg. 
\begin{eqnarray} M = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} a_{1} & a_{2} & b_{1} & b_{2} \\ a_{3} & a_{4} & b_{3} & b_{4} \\ c_{1} & c_{2} & d_{1} & d_{2} \\ c_{3} & c_{4} & d_{3} & d_{4} \end{array} \right), \end{eqnarray}
now $M.M$ in Mathematica gives the result which is correctly of the form,
\begin{eqnarray} \left(\begin{array}{cc} A.A+B.C & A.B+B.D \\ C.A+D.C & C.B+D.D \end{array} \right) \quad \quad \quad \quad (1) \end{eqnarray} 
(with the interpretation that the $(2 \times 2)$ blocks of $M.M$ are the elements of (1).)

Thanks for all comments.

Comment: In that regard: have you seen `ArrayFlatten[]`?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the only way to do that is using ArrayFlatten

Comment: Please post code in Mathematica format rather than images.  Also, note that your answer is much the same as an earlier comment.