# How do you concatenate matrices? And how do you make block matrices?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

This is pretty trivial to do in Matlab, but I have not seen a function for it in *Mathematica*.  Here is how you can do it with `Join` and `Transpose`.  Is there an easier way to do it than this?

```
(*Concatenate Matrix Right*)
A1 = Table[Subscript[a1, i, j], {i, n}, {j, n}];
A2 = Table[Subscript[a2, i, j], {i, n}, {j, m}];
Transpose[Join[Transpose[A1], Transpose[A2]]] // MatrixForm

(*Concatenate  Matrix Below*)
A1 = Table[Subscript[a1, i, j], {i, n}, {j, n}];
A2 = Table[Subscript[a2, i, j], {i, m}, {j, n}];
Join[A1, A2] // MatrixForm

(*2X2 Block Matrix*)
A11 = Table[Subscript[a11, i, j], {i, n}, {j, n}];
A12 = Table[Subscript[a12, i, j], {i, n}, {j, m}];
A21 = Table[Subscript[a21, i, j], {i, m}, {j, n}];
A22 = Table[Subscript[a22, i, j], {i, m}, {j, m}];
Transpose[
Join[Transpose[Join[A11, A21]],Transpose[Join[A12, A22]]]] // MatrixForm
```

Sample output for `n=3` and `m=2`:

[image]

Comment: Check out `Join[mat1,mat2,2]` for catting on the right. And `ArrayFlatten` might handle more complicated cases.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This is a related discussion [Partitioned matrix operations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96295/partitioned-matrix-operations/). (And it is not something that can be done trivially in Matlab.)

Comment: Do you see those manually drawn lines in the matrixes in the question above? I made the [MatrixFormDivided](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MatrixFormDivided/) resource function so that you don't have to manually draw them.

Answer (score 35):

As [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) suggested in the comment, `ArrayFlatten` is the way.

- `ArrayFlatten[{{A1, A2}}] // MatrixForm` gives your `Out[198]`
- `ArrayFlatten[{{A1}, {A2}}] // MatrixForm` gives your `Out[201]`
- `ArrayFlatten[{{A11, A12}, {A21, A22}}] // MatrixForm` gives your `Out[206]`

Answer (score 15):

From the application tab on Join:

[image]

Comment: It often pays to read the docs. ;)

Answer (score 12):

Just for fun, the more complex construction of block matrices may also be accomplished using `SparseArray`:

```
SparseArray[{
   Band[{1, 1}] -> A11, Band[{1, 4}] -> A12,
   Band[{4, 1}] -> A21, Band[{4, 4}] -> A22},
  {5, 5}
] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]