# Solve a system by Cramer's rule using loop

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, procedural-programming

Consider the linear system AX=B,where A=`{{3, 0, 2}, {-3, 2, 2}, {2, -3, 3}}`,B=`{{3}, {-1}, {4}}` and x=`{{x},{y},{z}}`.So i tried like this:

```
A1 = {{, ,}, {, ,}, {, ,}}; A3 = {{, ,}, {, ,}, {, ,}}; A2 = {{, ,}, \
{, ,}, {, ,}}; For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++, 
  If[j == 1, A1[[i, j]] = B[[i, 1]], A1[[i, j]] = A[[i, j]]]]]; For[
 i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++, 
  If[j == 2, A2[[i, j]] = B[[i, 1]], A2[[i, j]] = A[[i, j]]]]]; For[
 i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++, 
  If[j == 3, A3[[i, j]] = B[[i, 1]], 
   A3[[i, j]] = A[[i, j]]]]]; x = (Det[A1]/Det[A]); y = (Det[A2]/
   Det[A]); z = (Det[A3]/Det[A]); Print["x=", x, " y=", y, " z=", z]
```

But i want to do this using **only one loop**.i am new user of mathematica.So can Anyone help me to figure out this. Any hints or solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609)?

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less i will try to avoid For loop.But for the seek of answer can you help me to solve it?!! Thanks for your link

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the solution, you may use `Inverse[A].B`. If you want to illustrate Cramer's rule, the `A1`, `A2`, `A3` matrices do not need to be constructed via any loop (using lower case letter below):

```
a1 = Join[B, A[[;; , 2 ;; 3]], 2];
a2 = Join[A[[;; , 1 ;; 1]], B, A[[;; , 3 ;; 3]], 2];
a3 = Join[A[[;; , 1 ;; 2]], B, 2];
```

then

```
x = Det[a1]/Det[A]
y = Det[a2]/Det[A]
z = Det[a3]/Det[A]
```

gives `13/23`, `-7/23`, `15/23`. You can verify that the `a1` through `a3` matrices are identical to your `A1` ... `A3`.

For more on the use of `Join`, refer to the documentation or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98406/how-do-you-concatenate-matrices-and-how-do-you-make-block-matrices). Also, to initialize a matrix for later use you may try something like `Table[Null, 3, 3]` instead of typing out `{{, ,}, {, ,}, {, ,}}`

Alternatively, you may just use:

```
a1 = a2 = a3 = A;
a1[[;; , 1]] = a2[[;; , 2]] = a3[[;; , 3]] = Flatten[B];
{x, y, z} = Det[#]/Det[A] & /@ {a1, a2, a3}
```

Comment: only tangentially: in general, `LinearSolve[A, B]` is better to do than `Inverse[A].B`.

Comment: @egwene sedai thanks for your answer but i really want to do it by loop.Yes i understood using 'LinearSolve[A,B]' maybe less working.but i want to learn it by loop method.could you update your answer? Thanks again