# Calculating in the group ring $Q[GL_n(Z)]$

Tags: matrix, group-theory

I am trying to use *Mathematica* to check some identities in the group ring $Q[GL_n(Z)]$. Is there a package/function of *Mathematica* to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What identities in particular?

Comment: Identities of the type in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.5048.pdf Proposition 2.2 on the top of page 6. Not exactly those but mine are of the same "type".

Comment: Long time ago I worked on certain polynomial identities algebras and I used Mathematica for experiments and proofs derivations. Since those algebras had representations in the matrix ring I used symbolic matrices replacement rules, and the functions `Inner` and `NonCommutativeMultiply` to represent and investigate identities. (See [this response](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96295/partitioned-matrix-operations/96319#96319) for an example.)

Comment: Thanks a lot this was helpfull!