# specifying a list (vector) of arbitrary length

Tags: symbolic, variable-definitions

When trying to do symbolic calculations in mathematica involving a space of dimension `n`, which is arbitrary but fixed, I'd often like to work with vectors that have arbitrary but fixed length `n`. So I'd like to have a vector defined like `vec = Array[v,n]`, which of course does only work if `n` has been initialized with an integer value before. I'd then like to apply some differential operators like let's say `D[vec,v[2]]`. Does anybody know an elegant way to do that (maybe using the new Inactive construct in Mathematica 10)?

p.s.: Interestingly enough mathematica supports sums of arbitrary length, which for example enables the following kind of symbolic computation:

```
x /: D[x[i_], x[j_], NonConstants -> {x}] := KroneckerDelta[i, j];
D[Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}], x[2], NonConstants -> x];
```

which yields the correct result:

> Piecewise[{{1, n > 1}}, 0]

Comment: try suggestions provided in the answer here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19934/tensor-analysis

Comment: Mathematica 9 added built-in functionality about symbolic tensors calculation. Here is a list of them http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/SymbolicTensors.html

Comment: That should read `D[vec, v[2]]`, surely...

Comment: @Gleno: exactly, thanks, has been edited