# Speeding up inversion of symbolic matrices by invoking caching

Tags: matrix, symbolic, performance-tuning, inverse, caching

Is it possible to reduce the computation time taken to find inverse of symbolic matrices **USING CACHING TECHNIQUES** accessible (if any)?

I am trying to compute inverse of symbolic matrices of size 12x12. I see that when the timing recudes drastically when I repeat the calculation.

```
For[i= 1, i <= 10, i++,
 AbsoluteTiming[
    K1inv = Simplify@Inverse[K1];
    ][[1]] // Print
 ]
```

gives output timings

```
21.6312373
2.9041661
1.2300704
1.2350706
1.2360707
1.2270702
1.2260701
1.2340706
1.2630723
1.3620779
```

Is there a way to USE the CACHING to speedup the computations of such matrices in general?

This [link on SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-to-symbolically-do-matrix-block-inversion) points in that direction, but not answers the caching aspect

**EDIT 1:**

To be precise, the question is,

- is there any predicatable takeaway from the caching - i.e. something
  that I can count on (in terms of time-saving)?
- Is there anything I can do as a user to speedup further operations.

This question arises since I am not aware of how exactly caching helps - does it extend to only the EXACT SAME matrix (wherein memoization would solve it) OR does the caching speedup inversions of the SAME ORDER (i.e. for ANY other matrix of 12x12) OR would it speedup ANY ORDER less than the current order OR anything else ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  As you demonstrate, caching is already being used.  What else are you looking for?  If you want to implement caching yourself, look up [memoization](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html).

Comment: Sorry. My question was, is there any predicatable takeaway from the caching - i.e. something that I can count on (in terms of time-saving)? Is there anything I can do as a user to speedup further operations. The doubt here is since I am not aware of how the exactly caching helps - does it extend to only the EXACT SAME matrix (wherein memoization would solve it) OR does the caching speedup inversions of the SAME ORDER (i.e. for ANY other matrix of 12x12) OR would it speedup ANY ORDER less than the current order OR anything else ?

Comment: If you need caching you can control, then you can implement it yourself using memoization (see the link above).

Comment: (1) What internal caching has sped up in this case is not `Inverse` but rather `Simplify`.

Comment: (2) If you define your own inversion by cofactors (not using the built-in `Method->"CofactorExpansion"`) then you have the ability to memoize (cache) all cofactors you construct. This can make for good speed. It might also dine on all your RAM and maybe gnash on your hard drive.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful, but if indeed the matrix is invertible and a symbolic inverse is really necessary, it might be possible to divide it into a block matrix format 
$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{array}
\right)$ where $A,B,C,D$ are $6\times 6$ matrices and use the result at http://www.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~jang/book/addenda/matinv/matinv/.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau thanks for pointing out that Simplify benefits from caching (and not Inverse) - something new. I was thinking something along the lines of DumpsterDoofus's answer, which executes faster than the Inverse (I think I need to re-time it removing the Simpllify around the Inverse)

Comment: @myaccount_ram what were your findings eventually (after 2 years...)? I'm also calculating inverse of symbolic matrices so very interested :-)

Comment: @cherzieandkressy - I found that caching was always kicks in to help save time - it requires at least one computation to kick in.