# Calculating Eigenvalues using xAct

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues, xact

I'm trying to calculate the eigenvalues of the following system which originates from [here](https://inspirehep.net/literature/2144158) (Appendix B):
\begin{align}
     i{\xi}_{0}\hat{\tilde{\gamma}}_{ij} &= 2i\tilde{\gamma}_{k(i}\xi_{j)}\hat{\beta}^{k} - 2\alpha \hat{\tilde{A}}_{ij}  - \frac{2i}{3}\tilde{\gamma}_{ij}\xi_{k}\hat{\beta}^{k}\,, \\
    i{\xi}_{0}\hat{\chi}&=\frac{2}{3}\chi\left(\alpha\hat{K}-i\xi_{k}\hat{\beta}^{k}\right) \, , \\
    i{\xi}_{0}\hat{\phi} &= -\alpha \hat{K}_{\phi} \,, \\
    i{\xi}_{0}\hat{K} &= \hat{\alpha} + \frac{3b(x)\alpha}{4(1+b(x))}\left(\frac{\xi^{l}\xi^{k}\hat{\tilde{\gamma}}_{kl}}{\chi} - \frac{\tilde{\gamma}^{jk}\hat{\tilde{\gamma}}_{jk}}{2}\right) + i\alpha\chi\xi_{i}\hat{\hat{\Gamma}}^{i} - \left(\frac{2}{\chi}\hat{\chi}-\frac{\tilde{\gamma}^{ij}\hat{\tilde{\gamma}}_{ij}}{2}\right)\frac{\alpha(4+b(x))}{4(1+b(x))}\,, \\
    i{\xi}_{0}\hat{K}_{\phi} &= - \alpha\hat{\phi}\,, \\
    i{\xi}_{0}\hat{\Theta} &= - \frac{\alpha}{2(1+b(x))}\left(\frac{2}{\chi}\hat{\chi}-\frac{\tilde{\gamma}^{ij}\hat{\tilde{\gamma}}_{ij}}{2}\right) + \frac{i\alpha\chi\xi_{i}\hat{\hat{\Gamma}}^{i}}{2} + \frac{b(x)\alpha}{2(1+b(x))}\left(\frac{\xi^{l}\xi^{k}\hat{\tilde{\gamma}}_{kl}}{\chi} - \frac{\tilde{\gamma}^{jk}\hat{\tilde{\gamma}}_{jk}}{2}\right) \,,\\
    i{\xi}_{0}\hat{\tilde{A}}_{ij} &= \left(\xi_{i}\xi_{j}-\frac{1}{3}\frac{\tilde{\gamma}_{ij}}{\chi}\right)\left(\chi\hat{\alpha}-\frac{\alpha}{2}\hat{\chi}\right) + i\alpha\chi\left(\tilde{\gamma}_{k(i}\xi_{j)}\hat{\hat{\Gamma}}^{k} - \frac{\tilde{\gamma}_{ij}\xi_{k}\hat{\hat{\Gamma}}^{k}}{3}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\alpha\left(\hat{\tilde{\gamma}}_{ij}-\frac{\tilde{\gamma}_{ij}\tilde{\gamma}^{kl}\hat{\tilde{\gamma}}_{kl}}{3}\right) \,,\\
    i{\xi}_{0}\hat{\hat{\Gamma}}^{i} &= \frac{i\alpha}{\chi(1+b(x))}\left(-\frac{4}{3}\xi^{i}\hat{K}-2\chi b(x)\xi_{j}\hat{\tilde{A}}^{ij}+2\xi^{i}\hat{\Theta}\right) - \frac{1}{\chi}\left(\hat{\beta}^{i}+\frac{1}{3}\xi^{i}\xi_{l}\hat{\beta}^{l}\right) \,,\\
    i{\xi}_{0}\hat{\alpha} &= -\frac{2\alpha}{1+a(x)}\left(\hat{K}-2\hat{\Theta}\right) \,,\\
    i{\xi}_{0}\hat{\beta}^{i} &= \frac{3}{4(1+a(x))}\hat{\hat{\Gamma}}^{i} - \frac{ia(x)}{1+a(x)}\alpha\xi^{i}\hat{\alpha} \,.
\end{align}
The right hand side gives in matrix notation:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0&\hat{\tilde{\gamma}}_{ef} & \hat{\chi} & \hat{\tilde{A}}_{cd} & \hat{K} & \hat{\Theta}       &    \hat{\hat{\Gamma}}^{g} & \hat{\alpha} & \hat{\beta}^{h} & \hat{\phi} & \hat{K}_{\phi} \\ 
      \hat{\tilde{\gamma}}_{ij} & 0 & 0 & -2\alpha\delta_{i}^{c}\delta_{j}^{d} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2i\tilde{\gamma}_{h(i}\xi_{j)}-\frac{2i}{3}\tilde{\gamma}_{ij}\xi_{h} & 0 & 0 \\
       \hat{\chi}                 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3}\chi\alpha & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{2i}{3}\chi\xi_{h} & 0 & 0 \\
         \hat{\tilde{A}}_{ab}       & \frac{1}{2}\alpha\left(\delta_{a}^{e}\delta_{b}^{f}-\frac{\tilde{\gamma}_{ab}\tilde{\gamma}^{ef}}{3}\right) & -\frac{\alpha}{2}(\xi_{a}\xi_{b}-\frac{1}{3}\frac{\tilde{\gamma}_{ab}}{\chi}) & 0 & 0 & 0 & i\alpha\chi\left(\tilde{\gamma}_{g(a}\xi_{b)}-\frac{\tilde{\gamma}_{ab}\xi_{g}}{3}\right) & \chi(\xi_{a}\xi_{b}-\frac{1}{3}\frac{\tilde{\gamma}_{ab}}{\chi}) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
              \hat{K}                    & \frac{3b(x)\alpha}{4(1+b(x))}\left(\frac{\xi^{e}\xi^{f}}{\chi}-\frac{\tilde{\gamma}^{ef}}{2}\right) + \frac{\tilde{\gamma}^{ef}}{2}\frac{\alpha(4+b(x))}{4(1+b(x))} & -\frac{2}{\chi}\frac{\alpha(4+b(x))}{4(1+b(x))} & 0 & 0 & 0 & i\alpha\chi\xi_{g} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         \hat{\Theta}               & \frac{\alpha}{2(1+b(x))}\frac{\tilde{\gamma}^{ef}}{2} + \frac{b(x)\alpha}{2(1+b(x))}\left(\frac{\xi^{e}\xi^{f}}{\chi}-\frac{\tilde{\gamma}^{ef}}{2}\right) & -\frac{\alpha}{2(1+b(x))}\frac{2}{\chi} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{i\alpha\chi\xi_{g}}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
          \hat{\hat{\Gamma}}^{k}     & 0 & 0 & \frac{i\alpha}{\chi(1+b(x))}(-2\chi b(x)\xi_{d}\delta_{c}^{k}) & \frac{i\alpha}{\chi(1+b(x))}\frac{-4\xi^{k}}{3} & \frac{i\alpha}{\chi(1+b(x))}2\xi^{k} & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\chi}\left(\delta^{k}_{h} + \frac{\xi^{k}\xi_{h}}{3}\right) & 0 & 0 \\
             \hat{\alpha}               & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{2\alpha}{1+a(x)} & \frac{4\alpha}{1+a(x)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
             \hat{\beta}^{l}            & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{4(1+a(x))}\delta^{l}_{g} & -\frac{ia(x)}{1+a(x)}\alpha\xi^{l} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
          \hat{\phi}                 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\alpha \\
            \hat{K}_{\phi}             & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\alpha & 0 
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
I typed the variables such that it is easier to read. $\tilde{\gamma}_{ij}$ is the conformal metric with $\chi$ the conformal factor, $\xi_{i}$ is a arbitrary vector with unit vector with respect to the induced three metric $\gamma_{ij}$.

However, if I feed this matrix to Mathematica using the xAct package, I get an error saying that it found inhomogeneous indices which I don't know from where they originate.

How I implemented this in *Mathematica* is by doing the following.

```
packageList["xAct"] = {"xAct`xPerm`","xAct`xTensor`","xAct`xPert`","xAct`Invar`","xAct`xCoba`","xAct`SymManipulator`","xAct`xTras`","xAct`TexAct`","xAct`xPand`"};
System`$PrePrint = xAct`xTensor` ScreenDollarIndices;
xAct`xTensor`$DefInfoQ = False;
xAct`xTensor`$CovDFormat = "Prefix";
```

Next, we define a three-dimensional manifold $M$ and a metric $\gamma_{ij}$:

```
DefManifold[M, 3, IndexRange[a, m]]; 
    
DefMetric[+1, gamma[-a, -b], cd, SymbolOfCovD -> {"|", "D"}, 
  PrintAs -> "\[Gamma]"];
```

On top of that, we define a conformal metric $\tilde{\gamma}_{ij} =\chi\gamma_{ij}$ which I define with a bar (instead of a tilde).

```
DefTensor[chi[], M, PrintAs -> "\[Chi]"]
DefMetric[+1, 
 gammabar[-a, -b], cdbar, {",", 
  "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(D\), \(_\)]\)"}, 
 ConformalTo -> {gamma[-a, -b], chi[]}, 
 PrintAs -> "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Gamma]\), \(_\)]\)"]

DefTensor[\[Alpha][], M]
DefTensor[\[Beta][a], M]

    DefScalarFunction[p, PrintAs -> "a"];
DefScalarFunction[q, PrintAs -> "b"];
DefTensor[x[], M];
```

As an illustration, we define the unit vector $\xi_{i}$ as follows, together with a rule stating that its length is $1$.

```
DefTensor[xi[a], M, PrintAs -> "\[Xi]"]
xi /: xi[-a_] xi[a_] := 1
```

We are now ready to define the matrix

```
mat1 = Table[Table[0, {10}], {10}];
mat1[[1, 
   3]] = -2 \[Alpha][] gammabar[-i, c] gammabar[-j, 
    d](*delta[-i,c]delta[-j,d]*);
mat1[[1, 8]] = 
  2 I Symmetrize[gammabar[-h, -i] xi[-j], {-i, -j}] - 
   2 I/3 gammabar[-i, -j] xi[-h];
mat1[[2, 4]] = 2/3 chi[] \[Alpha][];
mat1[[2, 8]] = -2 I/3 chi[] xi[-h];
mat1[[3, 1]] = 
  1/2 \[Alpha][] (delta[-a, e] delta[-b, f] - 
     1/3 gammabar[-a, -b] gammabar[e, f]);
mat1[[3, 
   2]] = -\[Alpha][]/
    2 (xi[-a] xi[-b] - 1/(3 chi[]) gammabar[-a, -b]);
mat1[[3, 6]] = 
  I \[Alpha][] chi[] (Symmetrize[gammabar[-g, -a] xi[-b], {-a, -b}] - 
     1/3 gammabar[-a, -b] xi[-g]);
mat1[[3, 7]] = chi[] (xi[-a] xi[-b] - 1/(3 chi[]) gammabar[-a, -b]);
mat1[[4, 1]] = 
  3 q[x[]] \[Alpha][]/(4 (1 + q[x[]])) (1/chi[] xi[e] xi[f] - 
      1/2 gammabar[e, f]) + 
   1/2 gammabar[e, f] \[Alpha][] (4 + q[x[]])/(4 (1 + q[x[]]));
mat1[[4, 2]] = -2/chi[] \[Alpha][] (4 + q[x[]])/(4 (1 + q[x[]]));
mat1[[4, 6]] = I \[Alpha][] chi[] xi[-g];
mat1[[4, 7]] = 1;
mat1[[5, 1]] = \[Alpha][]/(2 (1 + q[x[]])) gammabar[e, f]/2 + 
   q[x[]] \[Alpha][]/(2 (1 + q[x[]])) (xi[e] xi[f]/chi[] - 
      gammabar[e, f]/2);
mat1[[5, 2]] = -\[Alpha][]/(2 (1 + q[x[]])) 2/chi[];
mat1[[5, 6]] = I \[Alpha][] chi[] xi[-g]/2;
mat1[[6, 3]] = 
  I \[Alpha][]/(chi[] (1 + q[x[]])) (-2 chi[] q[x[]] xi[-d] delta[
      k, -c]);
mat1[[6, 4]] = I \[Alpha][]/(chi[] (1 + q[x[]])) (-4/3 xi[k]);
mat1[[6, 5]] = I \[Alpha][]/(chi[] (1 + q[x[]])) 2 xi[k];
mat1[[6, 8]] = -1/chi[] (delta[-h, k] + xi[k] xi[-h]/3);
mat1[[7, 4]] = -2 \[Alpha][]/(1 + p[x[]]);
mat1[[7, 5]] = 4 \[Alpha][]/(1 + p[x[]]);
mat1[[8, 6]] = 3/(4 (1 + p[x[]])) delta[l, -g];
mat1[[8, 7]] = -I p[x[]]/(1 + p[x[]]) \[Alpha][] xi[l];
mat1[[9, 10]] = -\[Alpha][];
mat1[[9, 10]] = -\[Alpha][];
```

I get an error when I apply

```
Eigenvalues[mat1]
```

Hence my question: is it possible to write down this matrix (and if its correct) and is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: The actual code that generated the error is likely easier to work with than the latex equations. Consider either giving the code for the matrix and dropping the xact part (which diminishes your chances of getting an answer since probably few people here work specifically with tensor algebra) or directing your question to be specific about xact output/notation and providing the code you used so far.

Comment: I have edited my question with some code, if it is not sufficient, let me know and I will add more. :-)

Comment: I get a "IsIndexOf::nouse: Attempting to apply IsIndexOf on q[x[]]" and a "Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[ERROR[q[x[]]]] returned to top level error" when evaluating your code

Comment: Consider copy pasting the matrix

Comment: Why not copy paste the output of the matrix ? It's a 10 by 10 matrix. Consider using `InputForm` and the option "copy as plain text"

Comment: That gives me some weird output. For convience, I have put all my code into the question.

Comment: So the issue is in the output of the matrix ? Why mention `Eigenvalues` in the question ?

Comment: The error occurs when I try to calculate the eigenvalues of this matrix which I don't know why; this is maybe not the way to calculate eigenvalues using xact or maybe my matrix is incorrect formatted or maybe another reason.

Comment: I removed the Overscript printing and now I can get the the matrix

Comment: But there was an error when I used Eigenvalues. I took the InputForm of the matrix and copy pasted into a speraret notebook and chose a different kernel without xact loaded and it computed the eigenvalues

Comment: So as I see it you have the following options: Make replacement rules to change variables in such a way that xAct formatting will affect the code in `Eigenvalues`

Comment: option 2: copy paste the output of the matrix in a separate notebook with a different kernel that does not have xact and maybe avoid Overscript

Comment: option 3 : I can not think of a solution and do not know the origin of the problem but If you rather a solution than a work around, consider asking at the xact google groups: https://groups.google.com/g/xAct . The members there might be more familiar with the internal implementation of xAct.

Comment: sorry in option 1 I meant will not affect the code in EigenValues

Comment: Why the components of the matrix have indices? Do you mean `mat1` is a block matrix and what you want is to find the eigenvalues of a symbolic block matrix?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: Then `Eigenvalues ` is not designed for this, and it will recognize your `mat1` as a 10x10 matrix literally. Maybe you need something like [How to symbolically do matrix "Block Inversion"?
](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8/86893). Or more directly expand all the blocks into componnents.